# How to exclude a keyword within a keyword while parsing in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to parse a input sentence. 
I have a list which contains "MCA" and "CA", this list i iterate over the input sentence to find if it contains them.
But if the input sentence only contains "MCA" , i get the output as it contains both the keywords but in actual it contains only one word.

How should i approach this problem?

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Please clarify with a given example.

Comment: You could replace all occurrences of "MCA" in your sentence so that they will not count as occurrences of "CA"

Comment: the requirement is, i have a list of keywords which i will iterate over a input sentence to check if the sentence contains that keyword or not. if it contains that keyword, i will process the request based on the keyword found. The problem here is, say i have keyword "MCA" and "CA" in the list, and in the sentence i have MCA then, it identifies that sentence has both MCA and CA but in actual it has only MCA. And in another case if the sentence contains both MCA and CA in the sentence, i want to print that the sentence contains both the keywords.

Comment: If keywords are *words*, could you just test it for `" "+keyword+" "`?  Or would you potentially have issues with punctuation and/or string endings there?

Comment: Are you trying to match them as complete words, or as substrings within a word? "How should I approach this problem?" Stealthily, from the flank, bearing suitable weapons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find your keywords as distinct words, you may try to compose regexp, surrounding you keywords with `\b` tokens. This tokens match the border between two words.

Here are some examples how it works:

```
    System.out.println("MCA".matches(".*\\bCA\\b.*")); // false
    System.out.println("CA".matches(".*\\bCA\\b.*"));  // true
    System.out.println("M,CA".matches(".*\\bCA\\b.*"));  // true
```

Also note that if your keywords can contain regex-specific special characters, you need to escape them properly before composing the regexp.

Comment: System.out.println("MCA".matches(".*\\bCA\\b.*")); // false
here inside the regex, can i substitute a variable? I have tried but i couldnt do. is it possible to substitute a variable here?

Comment: @user3052550 What do you mean by "substitute a variable"? Something like this: `".*\\b" + variable + "\\b.*"`?

Comment: i had tried this way before. it doesnt work. it takes the variable itself as a string

Comment: @user3052550 please show your code so I can correct it.